# Flutter error: The argument type 'Color Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(dynamic)'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I'm having the error `The argument type 'Color Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(dynamic)'`  **in this line:**

```
final colors = data.map(getColorFromCode);
```

Here is the `data`:

```
late final data = [
    widget.result,
    widget.result2,
    widget.result3,
  ];
```

Here is the function `getColorFromCode`:

```
Color getColorFromCode(String code) {
  if (code.contains('A') && code.contains('P')) return Colors.brown;
  if (code.contains('A') && code.contains('pp')) return Colors.black;
  if (code.contains('aa')) return Colors.white;
  return Colors.black;
}
```

How to solve this error? If you need any additional details feel free to ask.

Comment: could you share what is the data type of widget.result, widget.result2 and widget.result3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try giving the data type to you `data` list

like this

```
final List<String> data = [widget.result,
widget.result2,
widget.result3,];
```